# Is it permitted to download data while in a background mode [note that's UIBackgroundMode not being sent to the background]

Tags: ios

I can't find a clear answer to this - all the previous posts seem to be relating to finishing a downloading task when an app is sent from the foreground to background.

I'm not talking about that situation, I'm talking about when the application has a UIBackgroundMode - my app has a requirement to register for certain location changes, when such a change occurs the app will connect to a server and download some data, the app should not come to the foregroud/display any GUI until some time after the data has downloaded (via the app creating a local notification).

I've looked through past postings but can't find a definitive answer to if this is permitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is permitted. When iOS wakes up your app with a location update you can download data and then post a local notification when needed.